# Error Content Editor

Tags: error-handling

[image]

Hi guys. I have a weird situation. Yesterday, Sitecore cms works fine. Today, the content tree from the content editor doesn't work. I have this error that says that is missing a `')'`. I added it to a folder, opened it with vs and saved it. Error still looks the same. I reloaded the server from IIS, but nothing changed. What can i do?

```
scContentEditor.prototype.turnOnSplitter = function () {
    jQuery('.scContentEditorSplitter').splitter({
        resizeTo: document.getElementById('MainPanel'),
        sizeLeft: scForm.getCookie("scContentEditorFoldersWidth") || 200,
        onEndSplitMouse: function (pos) {
            scForm.setCookie("scContentEditorFoldersWidth", pos);
        *** this one was missing }***
    });
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: is there any issue of Jquery conflict? Can you verify what has been changed in your solution?

Comment: no idea. i didnt changed anything or added another js file.

Comment: Looks like you are using SXA. Can you check if your theme is broken anyway, that might cause an issue.